# Applying a function to pandas rows with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with shape `12000x100`. I am attempting to apply a function to rows where a column values are `NaN`. My function is an API call where I may receive different responses.

```
import pandas as pd

# api call function
def api_call(v):
 
    try:
      r = api(v)
      return r
    except:
      return np.nan
      pass


df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'v': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                   'w': [10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
                 })

# Apply function
df['w'].fillna(df.apply(lambda x: api_call(x['v']), axis=1), inplace=True)
```

If a match is found in the API call, I get an integer score between 1-100, otherwise if there is an Exception I get  `{"status": 41}`.

Here's a sample response:

```
54
{"status": 41}
{"status": 41}
39
```

When I run this on my real Pandas DataFrame and I do not see the `NaNs` being populated. The DataFrame is exactly same in terms of # of `NaNs` in pandas series. I can't seem to figure out why it is not saving / replacing the `NaNs`.

It's a bit tricky to write reproducible code as the data is large and API calls require configuration etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because you slice your dataframe (`df['w']`) and you fill nan values in place (`inplace=True`). So you fill the copy not the original dataframe:

```
df['w'] = df['w'].fillna(df.apply(lambda x: api_call(x['v']), axis=1))
```

Comment: If I run `df['w'].fillna(20, inplace=True)`, it updates the original DataFrame.

Comment: It's not clear when Pandas returns a view or a copy... Personally, I never use `inplace=True` whatever the method.

Comment: @BeRT2me. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: I have just tried your approach of not using `inplace=True`. It still didn't work. can't figure out what's going on. pretty strange.

Comment: Can you try `df['w'] = df['w'].combine_first(df.apply(lambda x: api_call(x['v']), axis=1))`? Are you sure you have `np.nan` values and not `'NaN'` strings?

Comment: When I run df['w'].isna().sum() - I see there are about 7k out of 12k rows of data. They appears as `NaN` in the DataFrame when I print them.

Comment: Does `combine_first` work?

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your data? `df.to_csv('data.csv')` and `df.apply(lambda x: api_call(x['v']), axis=1).to_csv('api.csv')`

Comment: The real data is private and cannot share unf. I tried to run it on a sample of data using `df['w'].fillna(df.apply(lambda x: api_call(x['v']), axis=1), inplace=True)` and it worked.

Comment: Using `mask` worked for me. I don't know why tho. `mask = (df['w'].isna())

df.loc[mask, 'w'] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: ap_call(x['v']), axis=1)`